# Kubuntu bootloader overwritten by windows bootloader. Cant choose to run Kubuntu anymore!

Tags: installation, windows, grub2, dual-boot, kubuntu

My laptop had Kubuntu installed earlier but then I made a new installation of windows 7 ultimate. Now I cannot choose to run Kubuntu anymore as its bootloader was overwritten. How can I configure my system for dual boot ?

[I am new to Linux/ Kubuntu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this wiki tutorial:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair